# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was playing with SQL. AdventureWorks2012 database, table: Production.Products.

I was trying to get products which have `color` black and: either have `weight` NULL or their `size` and `listPrice` is above some value.

Here is query

```
SELECT * 
FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product 
WHERE (Color = 'Black') 
  AND ((ListPrice > 300 AND Size > 60) OR Weight IS NULL)
```

But this is the error I get

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S' to data type int.

Can anyone clarify what I did wrong?

Comment: can you mention the datatypes of the columns involved? it seems one of them is an `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all, your column(ListPrice or Size) is containing a value as 'S' and you are trying to perform numeric comparison operation(>) on the column which results in the error.

Comment: nice catch. Most of the initial values of Size where Numeric. Now I see some of them contain "S" too. Or "M".

Answer (score 2):

`Size` is `nvarchar(5)`, so that's where your S is coming from.

Check out the **[schema for Adventureworks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124719(v=sql.100).aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

Size = 'S' means 'Small' ? Do you know what datatype is used for the column 'Size' ? If it's a single character like S for Small and L for Large, you cannot compare it to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Size > 60
```

This is a numeric comparison.  The query engine will try to convert every value of `Size` to the same type as `60`, which is an integer.  Try:

```
Size > '60'
```

But, of course, that's an alphanumeric comparison, so it will be strings that are alphabetically after the string `'60'`.  You may need to employ `TRY_CAST()` or `TRY_CONVERT()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use Try_Convert().  This will return NULL for invalid conversions

```
SELECT * FROM Production.Product 
 WHERE (Color = 'Black') 
   AND ((ListPrice > 300 AND try_convert(int,Size) > 60) OR Weight IS NULL)
```

Comment: thanks. no need to convert. I was just experimenting and overlooked that Size column contained data other than numbers.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Just for fun try  Select max(Size) From (Select Size='60' union all Select Size='S') A

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava  S has an ascii code of 86 while 60 would be ascii 63

Comment: I also thought it would have to do with ASCII. But why it sticks to ASCII encoding, maybe I want comparison using UTF16 encoding? :)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Interesting thought, but I don't think it will matter.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Simple rule Digits before Alpha

Answer (score 0):

I think the Size column has data like `S,L,M,XL` hence the data conversion fails. Since you are looking for values `> 60` , int being higher presidence data type sql server tries to convert  `S,L,M,XL` values to Int and fails hence the error.

Easier fix: instead of using `60` use string containing values `'60'` for column size.

Something like...

```
SELECT * 
FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product 
WHERE (Color = 'Black') 
AND ( (ListPrice > 300 AND Size > '60') 
      OR [Weight] IS NULL)
```

Comment: thanks. no need to convert. I was just experimenting and overlooked that Size column contained data other than numbers.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava , I am not saying that you are converting, SQL Server is converting it for you,  it called `Implicit conversion` , hence you are getting the error.

Comment: Ok, but that is a "string" comparison I presume.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava not a string comparing anymore when you are passing an integer value (60 in your case for Size column), google what [`Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) is. When you try to compare two different data types SQL Server does the implicit conversion for you so it can do the comparison.